# html + CSS - split columns when cells have multiple lines of text

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to split rows of text using CSS for a particular div (the intended behavior is analogous to have a table with two columns).

I want the first column to have a fixed width, and that the second column to use the rest of the space. My problem is that, when the right column has a long text and I resize the size of my browser window (as if I were using a cellphone, for example), the right column is moved down.

This is the intended behavior:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Text 1  | This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. 
        | This is a long text. This is a long text. 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I get **after resizing my browser window** to a smaller resolution is this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Text 1  
This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a 
long text. This is a long text. 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code I'm using is the following:

```css
div.columns { width: 50%; margin: auto; }

div.columns div { float: left; }
div.columns div.col1 { width: 50px; }
div.columns div.col2 { width: 800px; }

div.clear { clear: both; }
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="col1">Text 1</div>
  <div class="col2">This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text.</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

This obviously happens when the window size is less than 850px. How can I specify that the width of `col2` is what is left after setting the width of `col1` equal to 50px, while keeping the intended behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `calc`. So you can have your right element the 100% size of the parent's element minus the width of your left element as it's width.

So for your `div.columns div.col2`:

```
div.columns div.col2 {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x3tek4ek/)

Comment: if you care older browser support, you should note that `calc()` is less supported than `display: table-cell;`, eg: IE-8 and opera mini does not support it.

Comment: Yes, but it is mostly supported by most browsers now. See [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Also Microsoft doesn't support anymore older browsers like IE8, IE9 and IE10.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a better solution as it doesn't require `calc`:

just use `display: table;` for parent div and `display: table-cell;` for columns as following:

```css
div.columns { 
  display: table; width: 50%; margin: auto; border: 1px solid black; 
}
  
div.columns div.col1 { display: table-cell; width: 50px; background: #f0fff0; }

div.columns div.col2 { display: table-cell; background: #f4f4ff; } 
/*no width required for second div, it will auto-fill remaining width */
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <div class="col1">Text 1</div>
  <div class="col2">This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text. This is a long text.</div>
</div>
<!--<div class="clear"></div> *** not required! -->
```